# Problems retrieving historical data through IbPy

Tags: data, python, interactive-brokers, historical

I am having problems retrieving 14 days historical data from IB. 
I recently made the switch from MATLAB to Python so I have a lot of catching up to do.
Where do I go wrong? All help is appreciated.

```
import sys

import pandas as pd

from time import sleep, strftime

from ib.ext.Contract import Contract



#Make connection
conn = Connection.create(port=7496, clientId=999)
conn.connect()

def var2(msg):
    print(msg)

conn.register(var2, message.historicalData)
def var3(msg):
    print(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #conn = ibConnection()
    conn.register(var2, 'UpdateAccountValue')
    conn.register(var3, message.tickSize, message.tickPrice)
    conn.connect()

    def inner():

        qqqq = Contract()
        qqqq.m_secType = "STK" 
        qqqq.m_symbol = "ABN"
        qqqq.m_currency = "EUR"
        qqqq.m_exchange = "AEB"
        endtime = strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
        conn.reqHistoricalData(1,qqqq,endtime,"14 D","1 min","BID",1,1)
        data = reqHistoricalData


conn.disconnect()
```

Comment: You didn't call the `inner()` function.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: You defined a function `def inner()` in your code, but you never call the function, put `inner()` on the line right after `conn.connect()` so it call the `inner()` function. If you still have error, post your error code.

Comment: Your code has several mistake other than the one that I mentioned above. I could clean-up code for you, however I don't use IbPy anymore. [IbPy](https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/wiki/Getting-Started) is a third-party implementation that provided very limited documentation. If you are new to IB python programming, I would suggest to switch to [Interactive Broker native IB API software package](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5041) and it has excellent [API documentation](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/#gsc.tab=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code, one obvious is having an `inner()` function without calling it. Here is an example that I clean up based on your code. I added a few comments in my code the explain what's going on. Also see my comments on your original post.

```
from time import sleep, strftime
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract


def historical_data_handler(msg):
    # The response data callback function
    # print (msg.reqId, msg.date, msg.open, msg.close, msg.high, msg.low)
    print(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Establish IB connection, make sure you have the correct port, clientId
    conn = ibConnection(host='127.0.0.1', port=7496, clientId=999)

    # Register the response callback function and type of data to be returned
    conn.register(historical_data_handler, message.historicalData)
    conn.connect()

    # Establish a Contract object and the params for the request
    req = Contract()
    req.m_secType = "STK" 
    req.m_symbol = "ABN"
    req.m_currency = "EUR"
    req.m_exchange = "AEB"
    endtime = strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
    conn.reqHistoricalData(1,req,endtime,"14 D","1 min","BID",1,1)

    # Make sure the connection don't get disconnected prior the response data return
    sleep(5)
    conn.disconnect()
```